# how to determine x and y position for graph type in echart

Tags: charts, echarts

From the given examples for graph series, I see the graph nodes are getting loaded from JSON files, where each node has corresponding x and y position hard-coded.

```
"nodes": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Myriel",
        "symbolSize": 19.12381,
        "x": -266.82776,
        "y": 299.6904,
        "value": 28.685715,
        "category": 0
      },
 ...
```

How do I get to determine the position for my given dataset? Do i need to iterate through all my nodes and do some logic to dynamically determine those position so that the node wont get overlapped?

Answer (score -1):

You can set `layout` parameter. Echarts will calculate the postions for you. https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=graph-force